# Merge Vertices by Distance & Center

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is there a way to merge vertices by distance and center?  Trying to turn grooves into V's.

[image: bloop]

Or maybe just an easier way to do this entirely, I've been doing it a lot lately and it's getting tedious.

I want to:

With a face, create equidistant V grooves along it.

current method:

- Ctrl+r loop cut and slide
- E extrude faces
- tediously select each
  vertex pair and merge center

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the Pivot point to individual origins

[image]

Also. when you find yourself doing the same thing on many similar pieces, it is time to think of using instancing or arrays, so that you edit only one object and the copies are changed as well.

Comment: This allows me to get them close so i can merge distance and be close enough

Answer (score 4):

@cegaton is right, instancing is almost certainly the way to go.. but just to explore some operators, and the way they automatically select on completion ....

With Orientation set to 'Normal' and Pivot set to 'Individual Origins'

- Select top and bottom edges
- Right-click menu 'Subdivide' with the number of grooves per face
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel with 2 segments
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad -</kbd>  reduce the selection
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> move reduced selection along face normals.

[image]

In your case, to go your way, and select the faces whose vertices are to be merged, you could probably <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> select faces by similar area to a sample, and, again, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad -</kbd>  reduce the selection to the front faces.

Comment: Oh bevel with 2 segments, that is helpful.  Also reduce selection saves a lot of time. (Dang, can't mark 2 as answers)

Comment: @Daoidh     No problem! It's just nice to be able to share some of the little things which make Blender a fast modeler, once you think in its way.

Comment: You can change the accepted answer at anytime if you find other answers more useful. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Add a cube and scale it along Z axis;

Select vertex pairs and merge them center;

Extrude edges of the opposite face by the same amount;

Use array modifier as mamy times as you want.